# Different Product Key & License in Microsoft Volume License and What is MAK Activations Used/Available*?

Tags: windows, licensing

First, I dont familiar with windows volume license ...
My company give me an access to check how many windows os license left

In Microsoft Volume License, in menu License summary its show some thing like this :

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP30d.png)

I have questions :

1. It's show MAX Activations Used/Available with value = 1/50 is it means i have activated 1 time with the product key and i have 49 more ?
2. Whats is different between product keys and Licenses ? 
   in Product Key tab its show me more than 1 OS but in licenses tab only show windows 8, like this :
   [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsFF6.png)

*sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: yes, it means 1 of 50 activations was done.

2: License: Legal construct. Key: Physical code to activate. A key can be tied to a licence that allows 100 activations or more.

Generally: Do not go where you are now - check your paperwork. It is irrelevant how many activations you have - you must know the license under the keys. It may well be the licenses are limited. Check your paperwork.

Comment: Ok thanks for ur help, 

1 more question, in this statment "... its irrelevant how many activations u have ..." 

do u mean : maybe i have activate a key more than 1 times ? and maybe i only have 1 of 1 activation not 1 of 50 ?

Comment: No. It means MS may give you 200 activations though your paperwork only allows 150 because activations may get lost and this is easier to handle for them.